# Is my context free grammar here correct?

Tags: context-free-grammar

So in preparation for an interview, I have been revising and studying by solving some CFGs, and here is a question, which I solved, but I feel like I haven't solved it right, given its boundary requirements.

> Give a CFG for the set of all strings in the form $O^i 1^j 2^k 3^l$ where $0 \leq j \leq 2i$ and $k=l$.

My approach: When $j=2$, $i=2$, and $k=3$ I started solving this (do share some of your tips and hints in solving CFGs, it would help me alot and I would appreciate your expertise tips) I produced a string

$$011222333$$

And given that, after analyzing it, I came up with this grammar

$$S \to OA$$
$$A \to 1A1B|\epsilon$$
$$B \to 2BC|\epsilon$$
$$C \to 3c|\epsilon$$

I was able to produce that string from the above grammar, but I feel like I was intentionally selecting and choosing when to choose epsilon, almost forcing my grammar to work, it felt weird.

Your assistance, plus tips will greatly help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, split your language in two, that is, $L_1 = \{\mathtt{0}^i\mathtt{1}^j \mid 0 \leq j \leq 2i\}$ and $L_2 = \{\mathtt{2}^k\mathtt{3}^k \mid k \in \mathbb{N}\}$,

$$S \to L_1L_2.$$

Now, $L_2$ is simply

$$L_2 \to \mathtt{2}\,L_2\mathtt{3} \mid \varepsilon$$

while the first one can be done using this simple trick:

\begin{align}
L_1 &\to \mathtt{0}\,L_1JJ \mid \varepsilon \\
J &\to \mathtt{1} \mid \varepsilon
\end{align}

I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: you are the man! That was such a frickin neat explanation. However, I feel like any input you ask me to produced, I can produce with my approach, why is mine considered 'wrong'?

Comment: is the language 01 in this language, or is it only 011 since i must be 2*i in the output?

Comment: String $01$ can be constructed like this: $(0(\varepsilon)(1)(\varepsilon))(\varepsilon)$.

Comment: but is that accepted? I guess the boundary is confusing me. When it says, j<=2i, does that mean if I choose i =1, then there must be two 0s, or since the original i was 1, then there must be one.

Comment: the above question is really bothering me. An explanation as to how these boundaries work, mean and affect the output

Comment: $0 \leq j \leq 2i$ means that when you pick $i=1$, then $j \in \{0,1,2\}$, i.e. all strings `0`, `01` and `011` are in the language. When you pick $i = 2$ then you get `00`, `001`, `0011`, `00111` and `001111`. Similarly for bigger $i$-s.

Answer (score 0):

Your grammar does not construct the language intended.  $\newcommand{\Ze}{\mathtt{0}}
\newcommand{\On}{\mathtt{1}}
\newcommand{\Tw}{\mathtt{2}}
\newcommand{\Th}{\mathtt{3}}$ For example, it can construct the following string:
$$\begin{align}
\color{red}{S}
&\Rightarrow \color{blue}{ \Ze A } = \Ze \color{red}{A} \\
&\Rightarrow \Ze \color{blue}{ \On A \On B } 
=            \Ze \On \color{red}{A} \On B \\
&\Rightarrow \Ze \On \color{blue}{ \On A \On B } \On B 
=            \Ze \On \On \color{red}{A} \On B \On B \\
&\Rightarrow \Ze \On \On \color{blue}{\varepsilon} \On B \On B
=            \Ze \On \On \On \color{red}{B} \On B \\
&\Rightarrow \Ze \On \On \On \color{blue}{ \Tw B C } \On B
=            \Ze \On \On \On \Tw \color{red}{B} C \On B \\
&\Rightarrow \Ze \On \On \On \Tw \color{blue}{\varepsilon} C \On B 
=            \Ze \On \On \On \Tw \color{red}{C} \On B  \\
&\Rightarrow \Ze \On \On \On \Tw \color{blue}{\varepsilon} \On B 
=            \Ze \On \On \On \Tw \On \color{red}{B} \\
&\Rightarrow \Ze \On \On \On \Tw \On \color{blue}{\varepsilon} 
=            \Ze \On \On \On \Tw \On
\end{align}$$
which is not in the desired language.

In fact, you can easily show that every string your grammar constructs has only one $\Ze$.  Working a bit more, you can show that the language your CFG constructs is (abusing notation somewhat) $$ \{ \Ze \On^n ( \On \Tw^* \Th^* )^n : n \geq 0 \}.$$

(dtldarek's answer provides a CFG for the grammar in question.)

Comment: as long as I can produce strings which are outputs of that language, arent I in compliance?

Comment: @Gaak: No. To be a CFG for a given language the CFG must construct _all_ and _only_ strings from the given language.

Comment: @Gaak:  If just being able to construct every string in the language were sufficient, _every_ language would be context-free (indeed regular), using the grammar with productions $S\to xS$ (for all $x$ in the alphabet) and $S\to \epsilon$.

Comment: @TaraB exactly, and that is what bothers me. I dont know when to stop and call it a day, or how to impose requirements

Comment: @Gaak:  I don't really understand your comment.  As Arthur said, you just need to find a grammar which generates _exactly_ your language.

Comment: @TaraB My comment is, if you look at dtldareks post, he says L1 -->0L1JJ I don't seem to get that, or know when to apply such requirements

Comment: @Gaak: In dtldarek's solution the rule $L_1 \Rightarrow \mathtt{0} L_1 JJ$ (along with the rules for $J$) means that for every $\mathtt{0}$ in the string there are _at most_ two $\mathtt{1}$s, which will imply that the number of $\mathtt{1}$s is no more than twice the number of $\mathtt{0}$s.  The only advice anyone can give you for getting this is eerily similar to advice for getting to Carnegie Hall: practice, practice, practice!